# Can I force an update to IPGeolocation data?

Tags: wireless-networking, geolocation, google-maps, bing-maps

So I just moved, so of course the MAC address of my WiFi router still shows me located at my previous residence (both Google and Bing maps). Do I need to wait until the next drive by from each of the various mapping services to pick up the new location or is there a mechanism to let them know that this particular MAC address has moved? Google maps has a widget that will locally correct location by storing a local cookie but I'm just wondering if there is a way to "advise the internet" that things have changed.